# Undefined reference error doesn't make any sense to me

Tags: c++, cmake, undefined-reference, linkage

I have this code here:
**Main.cpp**

```
#include "AStarPlanner.h"
#include <costmap_2d/costmap_2d.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   AStarPlanner planner =  AStarPlanner(10,10,&costmap);
}
```

and my class:
**AStarPlanner.h**

```
class AStarPlanner {

public:

  AStarPlanner(int width, int height, const costmap_2d::Costmap2D* costmap);
  virtual ~AStarPlanner();
```

**AStarPlanner.cpp**

```
#include "AStarPlanner.h"

using namespace std;

AStarPlanner::AStarPlanner(int width, int height, const costmap_2d::Costmap2D* costmap)
{

  ROS_INFO("Planner Konstruktor");
  width_ = width;
  height_ = height;
  costmap_ = costmap;
}
```

I can't see any mistake from me. The function is defined and my main.cpp knows about the class.

**CMakeList**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.4.6)
include($ENV{ROS_ROOT}/core/rosbuild/rosbuild.cmake)

rosbuild_init()

#set the default path for built executables to the "bin" directory
set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
#set the default path for built libraries to the "lib" directory
set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)

rosbuild_add_library (robot_mover src/AStarPlanner.cpp )
rosbuild_add_executable(robot_mover src/main.cpp)
```

But i get this error :
**undefined reference to `vtable for AStarPlanner'**
** undefined reference to`AStarPlanner::~AStarPlanner()'**

Comment: You are probably not linking the two object files together. What compiler are you using?

Comment: This is a linker error, not compiler error. Are you linking with the object file that contains `AStarPlanner`s function definitions?

Comment: I think gcc and cmake on Ubuntu 10.04.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have failed to define a destructor for   `AStarPlanner`. You may add it to AStarPlanner.cpp thus:

```
AStarPlanner::~AStarPlanner()
{
}
```

Consider [this advice](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/strange-inheritance.html#faq-23.10).

Comment: Shouldn't that be ok:  virtual ~AStarPlanner(); ?

Comment: No, that is a declaration. You must provide a definition, also. It can be as simple as `virtual ~AStarPlanner() {}`.

Answer (score 2):

I had a problem of undefined referenced too, which most of the times indicates for a linking issue...

**I solved it:**

**Similar to what Lee Netherton wrote**, but add it directly in your CmakeLists.txt

Make sure to add the file that the implementation of the function that failing is in.

In your example make sure that:

```
 add_executable(robot_mover 
                src/main.cpp
                AStarPlanner.cpp)
```

That will tell the linker which source files to look for all definitions/implementations against your robot_mover executable...

Answer (score 1):

The error means that although the compiler *could* find the defintion of the class for `main()`, but the linker *could not*.  You need to set up your compilation options so that yopu pass the generated `AStarPlanner.obj` to the linker when it tries to build your executable

The exact form of how to do the setup depends on what compiler you are using.

Comment: So does the extension of the object file.

Answer (score 1):

With `gcc` it should be compiled with something like:

```
gcc -o main Main.cpp AStarPlanner.cpp
```

My guess is that you've missed the `AStarPlanner.cpp` part.

**Edit:**

Hugh? The error you're getting just changed in the OP. This answer won't make a lot of sense now.

**Edit2:**

It looks like you're putting `AStarLibrary` into a `robot_mover` library. Are you linking to this library when building your executable? I'm not familiar with the `ros*` macros, but in ordinary gcc, the build command would look something like this:

```
gcc -o main Main.cpp -lrobot_mover
```

Comment: je sorry, looked in my cmakelist and found an error. So its not solved but the error changed ;)

Comment: Well, I think the linking happens in the CMakeList because for compiling I just need to call rosmake.

Comment: Yep, @Robᵩ is right! And for completion, the robot_mover name, is a package in the Robotic Operating System.

Answer (score 0):

AStarPlanner.cpp probably isn't being compiled/linked. Make sure it's in the project.

Answer (score -1):

Your

```
AStarPlanner planner =  AStarPlanner(10,10,&costmap);
```

references costmap but I don't see a definition for it (for the variable itself, not for the class).